# Splitting macro output into multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs through the data and outputs it in a specific format to a different sheet. Issue is, it errors out after row 65,536 has been populated, which I'm guessing is a limit imposed by MS:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = "datacol1"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "datacol2"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 3).Value = "datacol3"

Worksheets("data").Activate
SourceColumn = 2
SourceRow = 2
Cells(SourceRow, 1).Activate
targetRow = SourceRow
targetcolumn = 1

While Cells(1, SourceColumn).Value <> ""

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(targetRow, targetcolumn).Value = ActiveCell.Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(targetRow, targetcolumn + 1).Value =          Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, SourceColumn).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(targetRow, targetcolumn + 2).Value =   Worksheets("Data").Cells(SourceRow, SourceColumn).Value
SourceRow = SourceRow + 1
targetcolumn = 1
targetRow = targetRow + 1
Cells(SourceRow, 1).Activate
Wend
SourceColumn = SourceColumn + 1
SourceRow = 2
Cells(SourceRow, 1).Activate

Wend
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
.SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(targetRow, 3))
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

What can I add in this macro so when it does hit this limit of 65,536 it creates a new worksheet and keeps going?

Comment: You're using Excel 2003 or prior?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an Excel limitation.  I think the issue is your variable is undefined, so VBA is taking its best guess using a datatype that is insufficient to handle the row number you are giving it.  By changing the datatype to a `long`, I think you will fix your issue.

As a demonstration, this should address both issues.  For illustration purposes, I made the sheets split at 100,000 rows (rather than 65k to show it will work), but you can change this to 1,000,000 or whatever the real limit is.  I made it 100,000 just to prove it does split.

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim wsFrom, wsTo As Worksheet
  Dim SourceRow, SheetNumber, TargetRow As Long
  Dim val As String

  Set wsFrom = Worksheets("data")

  SheetNumber = 2
  SourceRow = 2

  val = wsFrom.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Text

  While val <> ""

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet" & SheetNumber
    Set wsTo = Worksheets("Sheet" & SheetNumber)

    wsTo.Cells(1, 1).Value = "datacol1"
    wsTo.Cells(1, 2).Value = "datacol2"
    wsTo.Cells(1, 3).Value = "datacol3"
    TargetRow = 2

    While val <> "" And TargetRow < 100000
      wsTo.Cells(TargetRow, 1).Value = wsFrom.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Value
      wsTo.Cells(TargetRow, 2).Value = wsFrom.Cells(SourceRow, 2).Value
      wsTo.Cells(TargetRow, 3).Value = wsFrom.Cells(SourceRow, 3).Value

      SourceRow = SourceRow + 1
      TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
      val = wsFrom.Cells(SourceRow, 1).Text

    Wend
    ' insert your sort logic here
    SheetNumber = SheetNumber + 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but this seems to be producing some strange results. It is outputting column 1 values to column 2 and not everything got exported to the new sheet.
If I could do it all in one sheet it would be perfect, I would definitely prefer not creating multiple sheets if we can.
For reference I have created a sample worksheet, please have a look
https://app.box.com/s/4uq8j828bu6u1hvt7aggamb0eiomno6t

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your original code... I thought it was swapping columns 1 and 2 onto a new sheet.  Was that not your intent?  Does it just literally move the first three columns to a new sheet?  I admit, I didn't dig into it a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is literally copying data from one sheet onto another.

Comment: My bad...  I made a couple of fixes.  Let me know if that's any better

Comment: This is much better ouput but it seems to be stopping after it finishes pasting values from column-3. Once it does that it needs to re-paste the column-1 values, then the header of column-4 then values of column-4, and so and so forth. The sample sheet I linked above should give you a good idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: My apologies, to clarify more, It needs to paste all values from column-1 from sheet-1 in column 1 of sheet-2, then take the header of column-2 from sheet-1 and paste it in column-2 for all column-1 entries then take the values of column-2 from sheet-1 and paste them in column-3 of sheet-2. Once this finishes, it needs to re-paste column-1 values from sheet-1, copy the header from column-3 of sheet-1, paste it in column-2 of sheet-2 (where last one ended) and so on and so forth.

Hope this clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: Any chance you can paste a quick before and after of sheet1 and sheet2?  I think I (sort of) get what you're saying, but you know what they say about a picture...  If you can edit your original post with these images, I think we should be able to nail this one down

Comment: I just figured it out. Turns out the sheet i was using was in xls format which I guess has a limit. After saving it as xlsm and re-running my original macro it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: That's funny.  I guess my original question (using Excel 2003) wasn't so far off.  Glad you fixed it.